# Use iOS URL Schemes for open Apple Settings in Safari IOS 17

Tags: javascript, html, ios, url, safari

We used the `<a href='App-prefs://prefs:root=Safari'>Open settings</a>` to go to Apple settings from Safari.
It used to work fine, but for IOS 17 it doesn't work anymore.

How can I go to apple settings in safari IOS 17?

Comment: Those URLs are considered private API for exactly this reason - They can and will break between iOS versions.